# libcurl to put stream of data instead of file

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

We are using `libcurl` [C API](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/) in order to send a file over SFTP. This works fine using a code like this :

```
....
fd = fopen(local_file_full_path.c_str(), "rb");
if (!fd)
{
    cout << "Error opening local file: " << local_file_full_path << endl;
    return -1;
}
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerList);
```

However, that means that even though we have our data available - we have to write them into a file, and then pass the file over.

I was wondering if `libcurl` provides an option in which, we could pass a stream of data, eg a pointer into a struct of our data. If that's the case, is there any example I could use? And does that mean changes are needed on the "receiver" end - as we don't own it.

Comment: I don't know if this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63152986/1737811

Comment: @mutantkeyboard HTTP is not SFTP. That solution won't work in this case, as SFTP doesn't use MIME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have 1/2 of the solution - [CURLOPT_READDATA](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READDATA.html) . You just need to pair it with a custom callback in [CURLOPT_READFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html), then you can pass a pointer to your existing data in `CURLOPT_READDATA` and have your callback copy that data into libcurl's buffer when it needs the data.

> This callback function gets called by libcurl as soon as it needs to read data in order to send it to the peer - like if you ask it to upload or post data to the server. The data area pointed at by the pointer `buffer` should be filled up with at most `size` multiplied with `nitems` number of bytes by your function.
>
> Set the `userdata` argument with the CURLOPT_READDATA option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a POSIX system, you can use [`fmemopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> FILE *fmemopen(void *restrict buf, size_t size,
>        const char *restrict mode);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `fmemopen()` function shall associate the buffer given by the `buf` and `size` arguments with a stream. The `buf` argument shall be either a null pointer or point to a buffer that is at least `size` bytes long.

Assuming you have a `buffer` and `bytes` variables of the appropriate type, your code would look like this:

```
fd = fmemopen(buffer, bytes, "rb");
if (!fd)
{
    cout << "Error opening local file: " << local_file_full_path << endl;
    return -1;
}
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerList);
```

If you're running on Windows, see [**C - create file in memory**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249610/c-create-file-in-memory).  It specifically addresses how to implement the functionality of `fmemopen()` on Windows.